# Drawing canvas in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, canvas, drawing

I am trying to create a simple field on my .aspx form where one can draw, this could include a signature or a name. After which i should be saved as an image (.jpg). I don't know how I am going to program this, any suggestions on how i should take this problem.

I have not done a lot of programming on this subject. I am simply looking for ways on doing this and haven't found a lot of useful information after a quick search.

(P.S. I don't have any experience with using canvasses and such)

Thnx for the suggestions!

Comment: This is kind of a broad question and usually "give me suggestions"-questions aren't good questions. Can you give an example of what you've tried? Also, a quick google gave this tutorial which seems good: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2665/saving-html-5-canvas-as-image-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Yeah, i realise that its a pretty bad question, most of the time I do more research, but since i don't have alot of experience with .aspx and i don't really know how to take this situation i tthought i should ask it anyway, thnx for the tutorial, i will look at it

Comment: This seems to close to what you're looking to implement:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432675/Building-a-Signature-Control-Using-Canvas

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-drawing-plugins/) page,

you will find tutorial with some jquery plugins to draw canvas in HTML page.